# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript

Quando chamo uma função, dá:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

JS:

```
function __startGame (__nome, __pronom) {
var canvasGame = document.getElementById("__startGame");
var secondEtap = document.getElementById("scndEtapGame");
var confirmChoiceInt = confirm("Você tem certeza que deseja escolher " + __nome + " como " + __pronom + " presidenciável?");
if (confirmChoiceInt) {
    canvasGame.style.display = "none";
    secondEtap.style.display = "block";
    function showMonLvl(a, b) {
        var spanLvl = document.getElementById("uiLvlSpan");
        var spanMon = document.getElementById("uiMonSpan");
        spanLvl.innerHTML = a;
        spanMon.innerHTML = b;
    }
    function addValue(a, b, c) {
        var spanValueEleitor = document.getElementById("eleitorValueMenuContent");
        var spanValueJuiz = document.getElementById("juizValueMenuContent");
        var spanValueJorn = document.getElementById("jornValueMenuContent");
        spanValueEleitor.innerHTML = a;
        spanValueJuiz.innerHTML = b;
        spanValueJorn.innerHTML = c;
    }
    function addValueXp(a, b, c, d, e, f) {

    }
    function changep() {
        var p1 = document.getElementById("u_06");
        p1.style.display = "none";
    }
    showMonLvl(1, "$50");
    addValue("$100", "$25 000", "$15 000");
} else {}
}
```

HTML:

```
<img class="img_seta" id="imgSetaDireita" src="imgs/setaDireita_png.png" onclick="changep();"/>
```

Por que será?

Answer (score 1):

Quando chamas uma função desta maneira `onclick="changep();"`, ou seja: quando chamas uma função diretamente no HTML; ela tem de estar no escopo global. Estar no escopo global quer dizer que a função deve estar fora de outras funções, ou defenida diretamente no `window` por exemplo assim:

```
window.changep = function() {
    var p1 = document.getElementById("u_06");
    p1.style.display = "none";
}
```

Neste caso essa função não usa nada da outra função `__startGame`, por isso podes mesmo defenir a função fora dessa.

Tens outra alternativa que é correres essa função, ou pelo menos o que ela faz dentro de um oscultador de eventos. Nesse caso podes saber quando o elemento é clicado e corres o código que precisas.

Assim em vez de `onclick="changep();"` podes fazer assim:

```
var sDireita = document.getElementById('imgSetaDireita');
sDireita.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var p1 = document.getElementById("u_06");
    p1.style.display = "none";
});
```

ou até mesmo assim, se a função estiver no escopo global:

```
sDireita.addEventListener('click', changep);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ariel, o seu problema é o escopo,  a mensagem que esta emitindo é que a função que vocẽ esta chamando é indefinida, ao tentar acessar uma função/metodo da função `__startGame()` chamada `changep()`.

Você pode colocar um parametro adicional a função `__startGame()` para executar apenas uma determinada tarefa.

**Exemplo:**

```js
var el = document.getElementById('meuElemtno'); // pega o elemnto button



el.addEventListener('click', function() { // no evento click 
  a('c'); // executa a função a() passando o tipo do metodo que é c();
}, false);


function a(tipo) {
  // encontra a o tipo e executa a função; 
  if (tipo === 'b') {
    b();
  } else if (tipo === 'c') {
    c();
  }

  function b() {
    console.info('acessando metodo b');
  }

  function c() {
    console.info('acessando metodo c');
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="meuElemtno">Click me</button>
```